# Getting spontaneous exceptions with Windows 10 BLE API

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm pairing with a BLE device and querying all it's services & characteristics in a small test console program

Every now and then I get this error during the query process:

```
Scanning for BLE Devices with service 00008000-0000-1000-8000-0012345678
Finding nearest device
Connecting to MAC CC12345678CF
Pairing...
  Waiting for DevicePairingResult result...
  Waiting for DevicePairingResult result...
Getting info...
  Waiting for GattDeviceServicesResult result...
  Waiting for GattReadResult result...
  Waiting for GattCharacteristicsResult result...
  Async op has Error: System.InvalidOperationException A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)
  Async op has Error: System.ObjectDisposedException The object has been closed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80000013)
  Async op has Error: System.ObjectDisposedException The object has been closed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80000013)
  Async op has Error: System.ObjectDisposedException The object has been closed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80000013)
Unpairing...
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at UWPWrapper.BLE.DeviceLister.ListServices(GattDeviceService[] services, Int32 level) in UWPWrapper\UWPWrapper\BLE\DeviceLister.cs:line 96
```

Where that row is just the if-case here, but it seems to happen in the for loop and many other places.

```
 var descResult = chr.GetDescriptorsAsync().Wait();
 if (descResult.Status != GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
 {
   sb.AppendLine($"{indent}    No descriptors: {descResult.Status}");
 }
```

It seems like the objects I'm accessing are being disposed while I'm using them, cause I get errors in really strange places evcen though I'm keeping references all the time.

Other questions point to this (listening to GATTCharacteristics.ValueChanged events). Any idea how to work around this?

FWIW, I'm writing a plain C# desktop app but using the WinRT API wrappers. It seems to work pretty well except for this issue.

Comment: Is it consistently happening for specific devices? I.e. are there devices where it *never* happens? Are there devices where it *always* happens?

Comment: I had some issues connecting with Bluetooth as well. Not sure if i got the same error though. However i also got the 'A method was called at an unexpected time.' error which sounds quite strange. It turned out, that the problem was, that i used some async method to connect to the device and did not use the await keyword and just stored the result in something like: var stream; then i tried to use the result of stream. using the async keyword worked for me. The asynchronous stuff could also explain why it happens only sometimes, cause the method may have been finished before using stream or not

Comment: @Fildor This is a specific device under development that I'm writing a test for. However, deallocating the objects I'm iterating through seems really wrong anyhow.

Comment: @Hannes I'm always waiting for "Completed" before accessing the results of any async op. If the result is anything else (error etc) I'm not accessing the results.

Comment: I have the same issue. The object disposed is in fact characteristic's parent service, not characteristic itself.

Comment: @grzegorz: Maybe we cannot access anything on the device (or service) after the first InvalidOperationException. Or are you getting the NRE directly?

Comment: @Macke: no, there is no NRE. When I get the exception, I look at the characteristic object. It's not null. Then I look at object's fields. The GattCharacteristic object has Service field. VS debugger in the Value field shows: 'activityCharacteristic.Service' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' (https://imgur.com/s09RYQr). The service variable however is not null, but debugger shows the same exception for Device field (https://imgur.com/a/92m3s).

Comment: @grzegorz, did you find a way to solve that? I am seeing a similar problem

Comment: @dumbledad: no, I didn't. But newer Windows 10 builds look more stable.